# Problem in Proving a Divergence Criteria of a Function at a Point.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence

Let $A\subseteq \Bbb R,$ let $f:A\to\Bbb R$ and let $c$ be a cluster point of $A.$ We can assert:

The function $f$ does not have a limit at $c$ if and only if there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$
with $x_n\neq c$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$ such that the sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $c$ but the sequence $f(x_n)$ does not converge in $\Bbb R.$
I tried proving this using the popular, "Squential Criterion for Limit" which states:

Let $A\subseteq \Bbb R,$ let $f:A\to\Bbb R$ and let $c$ be a cluster point of $A.$ Then the following two statements are equivalent:

- $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L$
- For every sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$ such that $x_n\neq c,\forall n\in\Bbb N$ be such that, $\lim x_n=c$ then, the sequence $(f(x_n))$ converges to $L.$

From this, result above, we can write the statement below, as a contrapositive of the above statements:

Let $A\subseteq \Bbb R,$ let $f:A\to\Bbb R$ and let $c$ be a cluster point of $A.$ Then the following two statements are equivalent:

- $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)\neq L$
- There *exists* a sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$ such that $x_n\neq c,\forall n\in\Bbb N$ be such that, $\lim x_n=c$ then, the sequence $(f(x_n))$ does *not converge* to $L.$

Having established these claims, we come back to the original problem.

Let $A\subseteq \Bbb R,$ let $f:A\to\Bbb R$ and let $c$ be a cluster point of $A.$ If there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$ with $x_n\neq c$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$ such that the sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $c$ but the sequence $f(x_n)$ does not converge in $\Bbb R,$ then $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$ does not exist.

This is indeed true, for if the limit of $f$ at $c$ would've existed, we could have said, that *"For every sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$ such that $x_n\neq c,\forall n\in\Bbb N$ be such that, $\lim x_n=c$ then, the sequence $(f(x_n))$ converges to $L$"* but in here, we find that $f(x_n)$ does not converge at any real point for a particular sequence due to which we can never assert that limit of $f$ at $c$ exist as then, all the sequences $(f(x_n))$ converges at a fixed point.

Now, for the other way round, we have to show, that if $\lim_{x\to c}f\notin \Bbb R$ or, does not exist then, there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$ with $x_n\neq c$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$ such that the sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $c$ but the sequence $(f(x_n))$ does not converge in $\Bbb R.$ This is the part that I am having a hard time proving. I need some help to prove the result in this direction.

Comment: @Feng I didn't get how did $x_1,y_1,...$ does the job? So, no that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: That proof based on a contradiction argument. Assume that for all sequence $\{x_n\}\subset A\setminus\{c\}$, the sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$ is convergent. Now fix any such sequence $\{x_n\}$ and then following that post we can construct another sequence $\{y_n\}$. Denote a new sequence $\{z_n\}$ by $z_1=x_1, z_2=y_1, z_3=x_2, z_4=y_2, \cdots$, then the seuqence $\{z_n\}$ satisfies $z_n\neq c$ and $z_n\to c$, but $\{f(z_n)\}$ is not convergent because $f(x_n)\to L$ and $f(y_n)\nrightarrow L$.

Comment: @Feng Thanks! I understand this now...